# SQL query to get certain matching rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was asked to write a query to return address for some customers in our system.

Below is a sample data structure for the table.

The goal is to display the results for customers with address-type = W and if no then to display the address-type = H. I have tried the the where clause with or clause, case clause and in my attempts I get the both records with W and H address-type.

| customerid | address-type | record-count | address1 | address2 | address3 | address4 | city | state | zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | W | 1 | 123 james ave | Apt 1 |  |  | City1 | AA | 11000 |
| 123 | H | 2 | 134 james ave | Apt 2 |  |  | City2 | AB | 23000 |
| 124 | W | 1 | 145 john ave | Apt 3 |  |  | City3 | AA | 32001 |
| 124 | H | 2 | 155 john ave | Apt 4 |  |  | City4 | AB | 12001 |
| 125 | W | 1 | 1000 wilson ave | Apt 5 |  |  | City5 | AA | 12009 |
| 126 | H | 1 | 11 smith ave | Apt 6 |  |  | City6 | AB | 14001 |
| 126 | H | 2 | 50 third ave | Apt 7 |  |  | City7 | AA | 15001 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to order the rows according to your specific logic and then pick the first one only for each customer.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by customerid order by address_type desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```